# Woocommerce Ocultar Subcategorías y mostrar solo productos

Tags: wordpress

necesito ayuda con un tema que a priori parece bastante sencillo. En Woocommerce una vez configuradas las categorías y subcategorías, una vez configurado el **Woo para que solo salgan los productos** miro la página y siguen saliendo las subcategorías como si fuesen productos. Hay alguna manera de solucionar este problema.

Answer (score 1):

Para configurar correctamente Woocommerece para que liste sólo los productos como tal,  debes seguir los siguientes pasos:

1. Acceder a "woocommerce -> ajustes" en el panel de la izquierda
2. Acceder a la pestaña "productos"
3. Acceder a la subpestaña "presentación"
4. Una vez allí, en la sección "presentación de la página de la tienda" selecciona la opción de "visualizar productos"

Siguiendo estos pasos, al acceder a la página que has definido como base de tu tienda, se muestran los productos como tal, sin agrupar por categorías.

Comment: Gracias Ernesto, precisamente eso es lo primero que hice,  en ambas opciones tengo marcado visualizar productos, pero cuando entro en una categoría, siguen apareciendo las subcategorías en la rejilla de productos. También he probado en productos/categorías a marcar todas las categorías y subcategorías como subcategorías, no como productos ni ambos, no se si me explico. Como no tengo la página publicada aún es complicado enseñarte algo mas.

Comment: En la configuración principal de woocommerce tienes en el apartado de "productos->mostrar" en la sección "visualización de categoría por defecto" la opción de "visualizar productos". Esto hace que se muestre los productos y no las categorías. Luego está la opción, en cada categoría, se puede sobreescribir con el desplegable "tipo de visualización". Deja seleccionado "Por defecto" y debería funcionar. Si no es así pon capturas con la configuración principal, la de las categorías y la página que no muestra lo que debería. A ver si damos con el fallo.

Comment: esta opcion:
Acceder a la subpestaña "presentación" no tengo en mi wp u woocommerce!!
en que versión aparece o en cual ya no esta habilitada ?

Answer (score -2):

Gracias por la info. En mi caso el problema es que todo artículo en galería muestra su imagen, precio, etc., pero debajo de la imagen muestra todas las categorías y subcategorías a las que pertenece. Esto no le interesa al cliente y de hecho es un engorro, porque ocupa espacio y se ve a que categorías ocultas pertenecen. No encuentro forma de quitarlo, aparecen tanto en las galerías normales como en cualquier módulo o carusell que quiera usar. No encuentro nada internet para solucionarlo. Las secciones que se suelene mencionar (por ejemplo presentación) ni siquiera aparecen en mis menús.

Gracias un saludo.